# sliding tab strip's apperance Android

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar, swipeview

I've got problem with implementing swiping tabs in Android App (compiled with API 21).

Previous version of my app had ActionBar Tabs and after compile with API 21 it looked like this:

[image: Previous ActionBarTab]

I want to implement Swiping Tabs (like in Google I/O App in "My Schedule" section here: 
)

[image: Google I/O swiping tabs]

but with apperance of ActionBar Tabs (dark one). Responsible for this is Class SlidingTabStrip (copied from Google I/O App).
Does anyone know how to get look of the ActionBar Tab in Swiping Tabs?

SlidinTabStrip:

```
class SlidingTabStrip extends LinearLayout {

private static final int DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS = 0;
private static final byte DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA = 0x26;
private static final int SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS = 3;
private static final int DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR = 0xFF33B5E5;

private final int mBottomBorderThickness;
private final Paint mBottomBorderPaint;

private final int mSelectedIndicatorThickness;
private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

private final int mDefaultBottomBorderColor;

private int mSelectedPosition;
private float mSelectionOffset;

private SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer mCustomTabColorizer;
private final SimpleTabColorizer mDefaultTabColorizer;

SlidingTabStrip(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

SlidingTabStrip(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setWillNotDraw(false);

    final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

    TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
    context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorForeground, outValue, true);
    final int themeForegroundColor =  outValue.data;

    mDefaultBottomBorderColor = setColorAlpha(themeForegroundColor,
            DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_COLOR_ALPHA);

    mDefaultTabColorizer = new SimpleTabColorizer();
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(DEFAULT_SELECTED_INDICATOR_COLOR);

    mBottomBorderThickness = (int) (DEFAULT_BOTTOM_BORDER_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mBottomBorderPaint = new Paint();
    mBottomBorderPaint.setColor(mDefaultBottomBorderColor);

    mSelectedIndicatorThickness = (int) (SELECTED_INDICATOR_THICKNESS_DIPS * density);
    mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
}

void setCustomTabColorizer(SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer customTabColorizer) {
    mCustomTabColorizer = customTabColorizer;
    invalidate();
}

void setSelectedIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
    // Make sure that the custom colorizer is removed
    mCustomTabColorizer = null;
    mDefaultTabColorizer.setIndicatorColors(colors);
    invalidate();
}

void onViewPagerPageChanged(int position, float positionOffset) {
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    mSelectionOffset = positionOffset;
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    final int height = getHeight();
    final int childCount = getChildCount();
    final SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer tabColorizer = mCustomTabColorizer != null
            ? mCustomTabColorizer
            : mDefaultTabColorizer;

    // Thick colored underline below the current selection
    if (childCount > 0) {
        View selectedTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition);
        int left = selectedTitle.getLeft();
        int right = selectedTitle.getRight();
        int color = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition);

        if (mSelectionOffset > 0f && mSelectedPosition < (getChildCount() - 1)) {
            int nextColor = tabColorizer.getIndicatorColor(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            if (color != nextColor) {
                color = blendColors(nextColor, color, mSelectionOffset);
            }

            // Draw the selection partway between the tabs
            View nextTitle = getChildAt(mSelectedPosition + 1);
            left = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getLeft() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * left);
            right = (int) (mSelectionOffset * nextTitle.getRight() +
                    (1.0f - mSelectionOffset) * right);
        }

        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);

        canvas.drawRect(left, height - mSelectedIndicatorThickness, right,
                height, mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
    }

    // Thin underline along the entire bottom edge
    canvas.drawRect(0, height - mBottomBorderThickness, getWidth(), height, mBottomBorderPaint);
}

/**
 * Set the alpha value of the {@code color} to be the given {@code alpha} value.
 */
private static int setColorAlpha(int color, byte alpha) {
    return Color.argb(alpha, Color.red(color), Color.green(color), Color.blue(color));
}

/**
 * Blend {@code color1} and {@code color2} using the given ratio.
 *
 * @param ratio of which to blend. 1.0 will return {@code color1}, 0.5 will give an even blend,
 *              0.0 will return {@code color2}.
 */
private static int blendColors(int color1, int color2, float ratio) {
    final float inverseRation = 1f - ratio;
    float r = (Color.red(color1) * ratio) + (Color.red(color2) * inverseRation);
    float g = (Color.green(color1) * ratio) + (Color.green(color2) * inverseRation);
    float b = (Color.blue(color1) * ratio) + (Color.blue(color2) * inverseRation);
    return Color.rgb((int) r, (int) g, (int) b);
}

private static class SimpleTabColorizer implements SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer {
    private int[] mIndicatorColors;

    @Override
    public final int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
        return mIndicatorColors[position % mIndicatorColors.length];
    }

    void setIndicatorColors(int... colors) {
        mIndicatorColors = colors;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the `background` setting to your `SlidingTabLayout` view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<com.example.SlidingTabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000" /> <!-- Background setting here -->

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPagerxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```